# R- group by 2 factor variables to calculate quartile

Tags: r

I have a data set which has number of records collected [reccount] by [hourtime] and [Feedcodes]. What I'm trying to do is to create a column, that tells me which quartile each record falls into (probs=0:4/4), so that I can set up an alert if anything falls below 1st or the 2nd quartile and I can investigate the feed to see if something is out of the ordinary.

I tried first with this, but realized it wasn't grouping by hourtime and feedcode

```
 df<-within(ds, quartile<-as.integer(cut(ds$reccount,quantile(ds$reccount,probs=0:4/4),inlcude.lowest=TRUE)))
```

Tried this but still it's not returning what I'm expecting

```
    as<-ddply(ds,.(as.factor(ds$hourtime),ds$FeedCode) , function(df)quantile(ds$reccount,probs=0:4/4))
```

I just need to add a column that classifies it as which quartile.
Here's the data:

```
    dput(head(dss,30))
structure(list(rownames = c(2371L, 2428L, 2459L, 2493L, 2573L, 
2581L, 2606L, 2633L, 2668L, 2683L, 2693L, 2748L, 2756L, 2819L, 
2865L, 2889L, 2896L, 2970L, 2988L, 3005L, 3047L, 3067L, 3111L, 
3132L, 3154L, 3177L, 3209L, 3241L, 3272L), hourtime = c(3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), reccount = c(2864L, 
3492L, 968L, 3271L, 6078L, 767L, 1365L, 6222L, 2515L, 3986L, 
4327L, 5764L, 3676L, 5338L, 6407L, 1217L, 3058L, 5673L, 3569L, 
3391L, 3169L, 6446L, 4201L, 884L, 3529L, 6461L, 3414L, 3246L, 
5486L), FeedCode = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "MDSWJD", class = "factor"), quartile = c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L)), .Names = c("rownames", 
"hourtime", "reccount", "FeedCode", "quartile"), row.names = c(NA, 
29L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ave()` to run the cut/quantile  by grouping variables:

```
dss$quartile <- with(dss, 
            ave(reccount, hourtime, FeedCode, 
                FUN=function(x).bincode(x, quantile(x), T,T)
                )
            )
```

Comment: Hi Neal, similarly how do I add median? this doesn't seem to work dss$median <- with(dss, 
                ave(reccount, hourtime, feedCode, 
                    median(reccount)
                )
)

Comment: Try `dss$median <- with(dss, ave(reccount, hourtime, FeedCode, FUN=median ) )`

Answer (score 0):

You got me confused with the quartiles, but having 5 groups {0,1,2,3,4}.
I don't know if I'm missing something, but here is a dplyr approach.

The first one calculates Q25% by group {hourtime, FeedCode} and flags everything below that. The second one splits reccount at 4 groups (quartiles) at each group and assigns the group number {1 to 4}.

Run the code step by step and let me know if you spot mistakes.

```
library(dplyr)

# example dataset
dt = data.frame(hourtime = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
                FeedCode = c("A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B"),
                reccount = c(946,184,1404,937,137,1199,698,1311,1302,560))   


dt %>% 
  group_by(hourtime, FeedCode) %>%
  mutate(Q25 = quantile(reccount,0.25),
         FlagBelowQ25 = ifelse(reccount < Q25, 1, 0)) %>%
  ungroup

#    hourtime FeedCode reccount    Q25 FlagBelowQ25
# 1         1        A      946 541.50            0
# 2         1        B      184 372.25            1
# 3         1        A     1404 541.50            0
# 4         1        B      937 372.25            0
# 5         1        A      137 541.50            1
# 6         2        B     1199 879.50            0
# 7         2        A      698 849.00            1
# 8         2        B     1311 879.50            0
# 9         2        A     1302 849.00            0
# 10        2        B      560 879.50            1


dt %>% 
  group_by(hourtime, FeedCode) %>%
  mutate(Quartile = ntile(reccount,4)) %>%
  ungroup

#    hourtime FeedCode reccount Quartile
# 1         1        A      946        2
# 2         1        B      184        1
# 3         1        A     1404        3
# 4         1        B      937        3
# 5         1        A      137        1
# 6         2        B     1199        2
# 7         2        A      698        1
# 8         2        B     1311        3
# 9         2        A     1302        3
# 10        2        B      560        1
```

Comment: Thank you AntoniosK for the detailed explanation!!